# Alternative for Range.SpecialCells method (excel) in Spreadsheetgear(excel)

Tags: c#, excel, ole, spreadsheetgear, vba

I am converting VBA and excel/OLE code into c# with spreadsheetgear.
I got stuck in Range.SpecialCells method. I am unable to found out replace for it in c# and spreadsheetgear.

In VBA Range.SpecialCells is used as:

```
SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell, ((long)xlTextValues))

SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, ((long)xlTextValues + (long)xlNumbers + (long)xlErrors + (long)xlLogical))

SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, ((long)xlTextValues + (long)xlNumbers + (long)xlErrors + (long)xlLogical))
```

Thoughts?

Comment: **Which `XlCellType` are you trying to use?**  It's important to include all relevant information and examples with questions.  See [these tips](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and also "[mcve]".

Comment: Isn't it `Range SpecialCells(XlCellType Type, Object Value)`? More [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.specialcells.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1).

Comment: You can probably an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bc%23%5dSpecialCells%20)

Comment: Edit1 is done please look at problem again @ashleedawg

we are using xlCellTypeConstants, xlCellsTypeFormulas, xlCellTypeLastCell

Comment: we are using spreadsheetgear for excel @AntiDrondert

Comment: we are using spreadsheetgear for excel @Jeeped